# Linter fails to spawn command Flake8 ATOM

Tags: path, atom-editor, flake8

I have added my anaconda packages to my path where Flake8 is located.  I also added the atom packages folder to my path where Flake8 is install for ATOM.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]